# js Диалог SaveAs

Tags: javascript, save

Направьте что почитать. 1) Нужно по нажатию на кнопочку открыть диалог для выбора места сохранения файла. 2) Сформировать файл (csv) и положить его по тому пути, который выбран в п1. В данный момент это реализовано на сервере. Хотелось бы сделать, чтобы каждый клиент имел возможность сохранять у себя файл.

Comment: А нельзя просто дать ссылку на скачивание csv из сервера?)

Comment: Возможно формирование и сохранения файла csv сразузу на клиента? Ну например. У меня есть какая-то инфа на странице. Я жму кнопочку (ссылку, картинку..это не важно), и у меня эта инфа забивается в файлик, вылазит диалог, я выбираю куда его сохранять, и сохранить его? Мне не нужно файлик хранить на сервере.

Comment: @SultanovShamil не хотелось бы таким способом пользоваться